# NSMutableDictionary always null

Tags: objective-c, soap, nsmutabledictionary

I am developing a simple program that creates SOAP message using NSMutableDictionary for the parameters. I don't understand why the NSMutableDictionary variable that I called from other class always return null value even I already add the values. I tried the setObject: forKey directly but it also doesn't work.

This is my code:

SOAPLib.h
   @property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableDictionary *parameters;

Calculator.m
SOAPLib *createSoap = [[SOAPLib alloc]init];

```
createSoap.Envelope = @"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
createSoap.MethodName = @"add";
createSoap.ServiceNameSpace = @"http://calculator.me.org/";

NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[parameters setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"i"];
[parameters setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] forKey:@"j"];

NSLog(@"Calc parameters: %@",parameters);  <--- returns i = 2, j = 3

[createSoap.parameters setDictionary:parameters]; <--- set

NSLog(@"create soap param: %@", createSoap.parameters); <--- returns null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call:

```
createSoap.parameters = parameters;
```

instead of

```
[createSoap.parameters setDictionary:parameters];
```

Comment: where should I initialize it on the SOAPLib.m or Calculator.m? if in SOAPLib.m, it doesn't have a viewDidLoad because I made it as a library.. how can I possibly do it?

Comment: All the changes I suggested would be made in Calculator.m.